# Limiting scope of included functions in PHP

Tags: php, symfony, scope, php-7.2

I want to include/require a file containing multiple functions from within a method. My goal is to make the so-included functions only available in the scope of the respective method and not in the calling scope. Is this possible in PHP?

E.g. in the following minimal example I want `foo()` to be available only from within the method `buzz()` and not from the surrounding scope (which unfortunately it is).

```php
// foo.php

<?php
function foo()
{
    return "foo";
}
```

```php
// bar.php

<?php
class Bar 
{
    public function buzz()
    {
         require_once("foo.php");
         return foo();
    }
}

$bar = new Bar();

// should work
echo $bar->buzz();

// should not work
echo foo();
```

The general task is to wrap function from a legacy code-base in methods of a Symfony service. Accessing the old functions should only be possible by calling the respective methods. The old functions should therefor not be in global scope.

A major limitation is the functions in `foo.php` being part of a legacy codebase that I cannot modify.

Comment: Perhaps you would be better off declaring it as a trait (https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.traits.php).  At the moment you are trying to have nested functions, which isn't particularly OO.

Comment: Maybe [namespaces](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.namespaces.definition.php) will be some help?

Comment: @NigelRen The functions are from a legacy codebase that I cannot modify. My goal is to wrap them in class methods in the new project (until they are eventually replaced) to only provice an OO interface to them.

Answer (score 0):

> My goal is to make the so-included functions only available in the
>   scope of the respective method and not in the calling scope. Is this
>   possible in PHP?

Not directly. Un-namespaced functions that aren't class methods are always global scope. If you simply don't want them in the global scope, then just declare them in a namespace. They'll still be callable from any scope however.

If that's not sufficient, there's a (rather ugly) alternative. Since variables defined in a function are available only to that function, you can approximate what you're trying to do by using anonymous functions assigned to a variable. These will effectively disappear at the end of the function.

foo.php

```
$function = function()
{
    return "foo";
};
```

bar.php

```
class Bar 
{
    public function buzz()
    {
        require_once 'foo.php';
        $function();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you! Unfortunately the requirement is to not touch the file `foo.php` (legacy codebase that is still being extended) which probably won't allow for either of the methods you mentioned.

Comment: @SimonFromme That should probably be in your question as it is a major limitation to any solution.

Comment: If you can't touch `foo.php` then I think you're out of luck, as `require_once` resets the namespace and the function will always be global.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get creative, you can rewrite the file to include a namespace declaration before you require it. This might look something like this:

```
function wrapInNamespace(string $req): string
{
    // Namespaces have to start with a letter, unique IDs might not
    $tempNamespace = 'a' . uniqid();
    $namespaceDeclaration = sprintf("namespace %s;\r\n", $tempNamespace);

    $lines = file($req);

    array_splice($lines, 1, null, $namespaceDeclaration);

    $temp = tmpfile();
    fwrite($temp, implode('', $lines));
    require_once(stream_get_meta_data($temp)['uri']);
    fclose($temp);

    return $tempNamespace;
}
```

The `array_splice` line adds a dynamically generated namespace declaration on the second line of the file, and we then return it so you can reference the functions later. This is done via a temp file.

The ugly part is that when actually calling them, you'll need to assign a namespaced identifier, since as far as I know it's not possible to call a function in a dynamic namespace on one line (I'd be very happy to be told different):

```
class Bar
    public function buzz()
    {
        $tempNamespace = wrapInNamespace('foo.php');
        $func = "\\$tempNamespace\\foo";
        $func();
    }
}
```

All put together, this means you can do this:

```
echo (new Bar)->buzz();
# foo

foo();
# PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function foo() ...
```

This all requires that your files start with `<?php` on the first line, and they don't contain any other namespace declarations. Calling `wrapInNamespace` twice with the same file will get you two completely different versions of the file - as long as you don't leak the namespace out of your `buzz` method, it's not callable from anywhere else. Whether this is helpful or not will depend on exactly what source files you're including; if they're simply a collection of otherwise global functions, this will do the job nicely. If they also contain procedural code, it'll be less useful.